# UV line-up problem

Tags: mesh, uv

I am trying to model a salt shaker can (not sure what the exact term in English is).
It looks like this:

[image]

I have created this:

[image]

The unwrapping of the "body" is straight forward, but the top causes me some troubles.
I tried to model everything from a single cube, so I did not make the "lid" a separate object.

The top looks like this:

[image]

But somehow the unwrap of the top is really difficult.

Here are my results:
[image]

What confuses me is that I have created 2 seams for the top, but I only have 1 UV "area".

If I do not add the second top seam, everything goes berzerk.

I have uploaded the model here:
http://www.pasteall.org/blend/38767

If anybody sees any raw mistakes on my side, I would be happy to hear about them. Thank you.

Comment: You did get two islands, they are simple on top of each other

Comment: Can you tell me how to separate them?

Comment: You select the faces that correspond to the island. Then go into the UV editor and moves those faces over to where you want them. If you wan't 'em to stay separate next time you unwrap, pin them with P

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I think this needs an answer

So what is happening is that your UV islands are stacked. To fix this you will need to grab one of islands. To do this, hover over an offending face and hit <kbd>L</kbd>. You will want to have "Keep UV and edit mode selection in sync" selected:

[image]

Finally, just use <kbd>G</kbd> to move the island into the correct place. You can keep it stuck there by pinning it with <kbd>P</kbd> so it won't move back if you unwrap again.